# Test prime number with GMP library in C

Tags: c, gmp

It's the first time that I use the gmp library and I want to test if a number is prime or not with Fermat test and Rabin Miller. The program works well with numbers of 20 digits but I want to test very big numbers with 300 and 500 digits or even more and with very big numbers it bugs, I don't know why !

here is the code

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void S_and_M(mpz_t a,mpz_t n,mpz_t h, mpz_t r) // square and multiply
{
    char * bin = mpz_get_str(NULL,2,h);  
    int i;                               
    mpz_set(r,a); 
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(bin);i++) 
    {                             
        mpz_mul(r,r,r);
        mpz_mod(r,r,n);
        if(bin[i] == '1')
        {
            mpz_mul(r,r,a);
            mpz_mod(r,r,n);
        }
    }
}

void M2Pow(mpz_t s,mpz_t S_pow)
{
  int i = 0;
  mpz_set_ui(S_pow,1); 
  while(mpz_cmp_si(s,i) > 0 ) 
  {
    mpz_mul_ui(S_pow,S_pow,2);
    i++;
  }
}

void Decomp(mpz_t x,mpz_t s,mpz_t t) // Function to decompose  x in 2^s * t
{                                    
    mpz_t y,S_pow;
    mpz_init(y);
    mpz_set_ui(y,0);

    mpz_init(S_pow);

    while(mpz_cmp(y,x)!=0) // while we don't find 2^s * t = x
    {
        mpz_set_ui(t,1); //we restart with t = 1
        mpz_mul(y,S_pow,t);// y = 2^s * t (we test the values)
        while(mpz_cmp(y,x) < 0)// we stop when 2^s * t > x
        {                      
            mpz_add_ui(t,t,2); 
            M2Pow(s,S_pow);
            mpz_mul(y,S_pow,t);
        }
        mpz_add_ui(s,s,1); 
    }

    mpz_sub_ui(s,s,1);
    mpz_clear(y);
    mpz_clear(S_pow);
}

void testFermat(mpz_t n, mpz_t rep)
{
    gmp_randstate_t state;  
    gmp_randinit_mt(state);
    gmp_randseed_ui(state, time(NULL));

    mpz_t i;
    mpz_init(i);
    mpz_set_si(i,1);

    mpz_t n2;
    mpz_init(n2);
    mpz_sub_ui(n2,n,1);

    mpz_t a;
    mpz_init(a);

    mpz_t r;
    mpz_init(r);

    mpz_t n3;
    mpz_init(n3);
    mpz_sub_ui(n3,n,3);

    while(mpz_cmp(i,rep)<=0 && mpz_cmp_si(n,2)!= 0  && mpz_cmp_si(n,3)!=0)
    {
        mpz_urandomm(a,state,n3);
        mpz_add_ui(a,a,2);
        S_and_M(a,n,n2,r);
        if(mpz_cmp_si(r,1)!=0)
        {
            printf("The number is composite \n");
            mpz_clear(i);mpz_clear(n2);
            mpz_clear(a);mpz_clear(r);
            mpz_clear(n3);gmp_randclear(state);
            return ;
        }
        mpz_add_ui(i,i,1);
    }

    printf("The number is prime \n");
    mpz_clear(i);mpz_clear(n2);
    mpz_clear(a);mpz_clear(r);
    mpz_clear(n3);gmp_randclear(state);
}

void Miller_Rabin(mpz_t n, mpz_t rep)
{
    if(mpz_get_ui(n) % 2 == 0)   
    {
        if(mpz_cmp_ui(n,2) == 0)
            printf("The number is prime \n");
        else
            printf("The number is composite \n");
        return;
    }

    int i=1;
    mpz_t a,y,s,t,n1,n2,deux;

    gmp_randstate_t state;    
    gmp_randinit_mt(state);
    gmp_randseed_ui(state, time(NULL));

    mpz_init(a);

    mpz_init(y);

    mpz_init(s);
    mpz_set_ui(s,1);

    mpz_init(deux);
    mpz_set_ui(deux,2);

    mpz_init(t);

    mpz_init(n1);
    mpz_sub_ui(n1,n,1);

    mpz_init(n2);
    mpz_sub_ui(n2,n,2);

    Decomp(n1,s,t);
    mpz_sub_ui(s,s,1);
    while(mpz_cmp_ui(rep,i)>=0)
    {
        mpz_urandomm(a,state,n1);
        mpz_add_ui(a,a,1);
        S_and_M(a,n,t,y);
        if(mpz_cmp_si(y,1)!=0 && mpz_cmp(y,n1)!=0) 
        {                                           
            for(int j=1;mpz_cmp_ui(s,j)>=0;j++)
            {
                mpz_set(n2,y);
                S_and_M(y,n,deux,y);
                if(mpz_cmp_si(y,1)==0) 
                {
                    printf("The number is composite\n");
                    mpz_clear(a);mpz_clear(y);
                    mpz_clear(s);mpz_clear(t);
                    mpz_clear(n1);mpz_clear(n2);
                    mpz_clear(deux);gmp_randclear(state);
                    return;
                }
                if(mpz_cmp(y,n1)==0) //Si y congrue a -1 mod n on sort de la boucle
                break;
            }
            if(mpz_cmp(y,n1)!=0)  
            {
                printf("The number is composiste \n");
                mpz_clear(a);mpz_clear(y);
                mpz_clear(s);mpz_clear(t);
                mpz_clear(n1);mpz_clear(n2);
                mpz_clear(deux);gmp_randclear(state);
                return;
            }

        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("The number is prime \n");

    mpz_clear(a);mpz_clear(y);
    mpz_clear(s);mpz_clear(t);
    mpz_clear(n1);mpz_clear(n2);
    mpz_clear(deux);gmp_randclear(state);
}

int main()
{
    int t=1;
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_init(n);
    mpz_t rep;
    mpz_init(rep);
    printf("########## Primality test ##########\n");
    while(t==1)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Choose an integer to test : ");
        gmp_scanf("%Zd", &n);
        if(mpz_cmp_ui(n,1)<=0)
        {   
            printf("\n choose an integer bigger than 1 !");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Choose the number of repetitions : ");
            gmp_scanf("%Zd", &rep);
            printf("#########################################################\n");
            printf("Miller_Rabin : ");
            Miller_Rabin(n,rep);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Fermat : ");
            testFermat(n,rep);
            printf("#########################################################\n");
            printf("tape 1 for an other test !");
            scanf("%d",&t);
        }   
    }
    mpz_clear(n);   
    mpz_clear(rep);
    return 0;
}
```

help me please.

Comment: Well, in `S_and_M`, doing `mpz_get_str` for what you really want is a bit of a hack [and _slow_]. And I _think_ you want to start `i` with 0 instead of 1 to get MSB. But, `mpz_tstbit` will be _much_ faster and is probably what you want. You'll need to know the bitno of the MSB and do: `for (i = bitno_of_msb; i >= 0;  --i)` You can get the MSB from `mpz_sizeinbase` for base 2

Comment: What does "it bugs" mean? Does it work correctly (but take so long that you assumed it locked up), or quickly return the wrong result, or crash, or ...?

Comment: @Brendan it dosen't return anything like if it is calculating the result and I waited it more than 30 min but no result

Comment: the problem is in the "Decomp" function  i guess in the while loop cause you'll never get this eq 2^s * t = x

Answer (score 4):

First; you can/should put extra printing in there (e.g. a "`printf(" Round %d\n", i);`" in your `Miller_Rabin()`) to determine if the code is still working and what it's doing.

Some performance tips (assuming your code is just taking so long that you've assumed it locked up when it didn't):

- A lot of time will be spent trying to find the modulus (e.g. in your `S_and_M()`). Because the divisor is always the same this can be sped up by finding the reciprocal once (with enough precision) and doing "`modulo = X - (X * reciprocal); if(modulo => divisor) { modulo -= divisor}; return modulo;`" (instead of using `mpz_mod()`). Note: To use integers only, you actually want to do "`shifted_reciprocal = (1 << bits) / divisor`" to get a reciprocal that has been shifted left by `bits` bits; and then do "`modulo = X - ((X * shifted_reciprocal) >> bits);`".
- When multiplying large numbers you end up multiplying each "digit" (word, 32-bit piece, ...) of the first number with each "digit" of the second number. For squaring, both numbers have the same digits so the intermediate results (of multiplying digits) can be recycled, halving the cost of these intermediate multiplications. This means that code designed to square a number can be almost twice as fast as a generic multiply (e.g. `mpz_mul()`).
- I have no idea what your `Decomp()` thinks it's doing (I suspect you wrote it thinking that `s` needs to handle numbers that are larger than the number of bits of RAM your computer has, which is absurd). In general you want to count the number of "least significant clear bits" (to find `s`), then do a single right shift to find `t` (like "`t = X >> s`"). For this, check the documentation for the GMP library (I think the whole `Decomp()` could/should just be "`s = mpz_scan1(x, 0); mpz_tdiv_q_2exp(t, x, s);`").
- Use a lot more trial division. For large numbers you can find the modulo relatively quickly if the divisor is smaller than a "digit" (word, 32-bit piece, ...). Also, you can combine multiple small divisors into one "big number modulo" by multiplying them, then use smaller (integer) modulos of the result. For example, instead of doing "`if( (mpz_mod_ui(dummy, big_number, 3) == 0) || (mpz_mod_ui(dummy, big_number, 5) == 0) || (mpz_mod_ui(dummy, big_number, 7) == 0) || (mpz_mod_ui(dummy, big_number, 11) == 0)`" you can do  "`temp = mpz_mod_ui(dummy, big_number, 3*5*7*11); if( (temp%3 == 0) || (temp%5 == 0) || (temp%7 == 0) || (temp%11 == 0) )`"; which is significantly faster. This can be exploited further by having (pre-computed) tables of "trial division divisor groups" designed to find the maximum number of divisors that when multiplied together will fit into a "digit" (word, 32-bit piece, ...). To maximize efficiency (maximize the number of entries the table has before products don't fit in a "digit" and I have to reduce the number of divisors in a table entry) I generate these tables using a "smalls and bigs" method (e.g. 19 and 137 are small, 421 and 587 are big, and 19*137*421*587 = 0x26578B9D = a number small enough to fit in 32 bits).
- You don't need big integers (mpz) to keep track of the number of Miller Rabin rounds (the `while(mpz_cmp_ui(rep,i)>=0)` loop). Convert your `rep` into an `int` before starting the loop and do `while(i <= int_rep` instead. Note that (for things like finding prime numbers for RSA-4096) 256 rounds of Miller Rabin is unnecessary overkill.
- Miller Rabin is embarrassingly parallel. If you have 8 CPUs then you want to use 8 threads, and want to do (up to) 8 rounds of Miller Rabin in parallel. Note: If you don't do enough trial division then the first iteration of Miller Rabin will frequently say "composite", and in that case you may want to do the first iteration of Miller Rabin with a single thread (and only use multiple threads after the first iteration).